# need to fetch data from 2 tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have two tables filter_categories and filter tags

```
filter_categories
id | category 

filter_tags
id | filter_category_id | filter_tag
```

i m writing following query to join these tables

```
"select filter_categories.filter_category,
filter_tags.filter_tag from filter_categories JOIN filter_tags ON 
(filter_tags.filter_category_id=filter_categories.id) where   
 filter_categories.filter_id='".$_GET["id"]."'
```

i m getting this result with php print_r()

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (

        [filter_category] => abcty
               [filter_tag] => sdfds

    )

[1] => Array
    (

        [filter_category] => abcty

        [filter_tag] => dgdfg

    )

[2] => Array
    (

        [filter_category] => abcty

        [filter_tag] => gdgdf

    )

[3] => Array
    (

        [filter_category] => abcty

        [filter_tag] => dgdfgf

    )

[4] => Array
    (


        [filter_category] => abcty
        [filter_tag] => dsfs

    )
```

)

But i need to fetch result like this

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (

        [filter_category] => abcty
        [filter_tag] => array(
        [filter_tag] => dgdfg
        [filter_tag] => dgdfgf
        [filter_tag] => dsfs
)
)
)

[1] => Array
    (

        [filter_category] => efg
       [filter_tag] => array(

  [filter_tag] => et
[filter_tag] => yu
 [filter_tag] => op
    )
    )
   )
```

can someone help me out..how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: You will have to format the data yourself, mysql cannot output the data like that.

Comment: how to sort that array if u know can u help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all modify your query like this to get the id of category

```
select filter_categories.id,filter_categories.filter_category,
filter_tags.filter_tag from filter_categories JOIN filter_tags ON 
(filter_tags.filter_category_id=filter_categories.id) where   
 filter_categories.filter_id='".$_GET["id"].
```

then suppose your result are coming into `$arrfilterALLDetails` array then just use the for loop to modify the result as want above like below.

```
 $arrfilterDetails = array();
 foreach ($arrfilterALLDetails as $key => $value) {
          $arrfilterDetails[$value['id']]['filter_category'] = $value['filter_category'];
          $arrfilterDetails[$value['id']][$value['filter_tag']] = $value['filter_tag'];
        }
print_r($arrfilterDetails);
```

Just play with this a littlebit you will get the result as you want.

Comment: Glad it helped you. Happy coding.